# Firebase storage Illegal State exception: expected a file to resume from

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm encountering an issue with firebase storage, I'm unable to find where the issue occurred(Mostly this occurred when app is not opened).
The stack trace of error is given below.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: expected a file to resume from.
       at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzl(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.zzx.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Can I know what's causing this issue and crashing of app and how can I resolve it such that it wont crash my app frequently?

Comment: Is it a new app?

Comment: It's an app which is in closed beta right now.